# Doubt in this question involving vector operations

Tags: vectors

> Determine the coordinates of the vector $\vec u$ that has module $3\sqrt 3$ and is ortogonal to $\vec v=(2,3,-1)$ and to $\vec
>  w=(2,-4,6)$ so that $\measuredangle(\vec u,(1,0,0))$ is acute.

I managed to get the answer which is $(3,-3,-3)$ and I didn't need this information about the angle. Am I missing some concept? Just to clarify, what I did to find the answer: calculate vector product between u and v, since the result is parallel to w, we can get an expression in terms of a real number a, and equate the module of the expression in terms of a to $3\sqrt 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other possibility is $-(3,-3,-3) = (-3,3,3)$, same length, same orthogonality to $v$ and $w$, but it would have a negative scalar product to $e_1$,
so the cosine of that angle would have been negative and the angle would have been not accute (less than $90^\circ$):

$$
(-3,3,3) \cdot (1,0,0) = -3 = 
\lVert(-3,3,3)\rVert \lVert (1,0,0) \rVert \cos \alpha
= 3 \sqrt{3} \cos \alpha \Rightarrow \\
\cos \alpha = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} < 0 \Rightarrow \alpha \in (90^\circ, 270^\circ) 
$$
Using some calculator gives $\alpha = 125.3^\circ$.

So that condition $\alpha < 90^\circ$ singles out your found solution from the two.